# PostgreSQL get parameter bigint array

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which has a column id with bigint type . I need to create function which will take a parameter bigint[] and in function I should check where id in (array)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(ids bigint[])
 select * from table where id in ($1)
```

Function creates successfully , but when I call it

```
SELECT * FROM my_function(ARRAY [1,2,3,4]);
```

I get an error:

```
 ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]
```

Comment: You want the `= ANY` operator, not `in`.

Answer (score 1):

As commented:

```
where id = any ($1)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21104